# how can we make a column having mutiple values in it as foreign key to another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have two tables

```
intent_sample(id,sample_data,intent_id,entity_id)
entities(id,entity_name,entity_id)
```

Since a sample_data can have any no of entities in it, I want to store multiple values in a single column and also want to link entity_id to entities table as it foreign key.

How can we do it.

I thought of using JSON data type in mysql for entity_id but is it possible to make a column having json data type as foreign key to another table

Comment: You DEFINITELY do not want to do this. See normalisation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a composite key

```
FOREIGN KEY (`id`,`entity_id`) 
    REFERENCES entities(`intent_id`,`entity_id`)
```

This will allow a relation between the foreign key in one table to the id's in another table.

I don't have all of the details so you can modify it to work with your tables.